# C++ / class A : public B, public C / What happens to B on ~C()?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual, destructor

I want to do some kind of garbage collection for a script engine based on a reference counter :

```
class HeapValue
{
private:

   size_t _refCount;

public:

   HeapValue()
    : _refCount( 0 )
   { }

   virtual ~HeapValue() { }

   inline void reference() throw()
   {
      ++this->_refCount;
   }

   inline void unreference() throw()
   {
      if( 0 == --this->_refCount )
      {
         delete this;
      }
   }
};
```

But my objects are not only HeapValues, they are also Scopes :

```
class Scope
{
protected:

   std::map< std::string, Value > _vars;

public:

   inline Value & getRef( const std::string & name ) throw()
   {
      return this->_vars[ name ];
   }

   inline Value getCpy( const std::string & name ) const
   {
      std::map< std::string, Value >::const_iterator itr = this->_vars.find( name );

      if( this->_vars.end() != itr )
      {
         return itr->second;
      }
      else
      {
         throw std::exception( "Scope::getCpy() - Accessing undeclared indentifier in readonly mode." );
      }
   }
};

class Object : public Scope, public HeapValue
{
};
```

Assuming that i create an Object, what exactly will happen when the class HeapValue will delete itself ? I assume it will not call the Scope destructor since a Scope is not a HeapValue ?

Thank you :)

EDIT : Added class Object definition

EDIT :

My Value class is a variant :

```
class Value
{
private:

    union
    {
        int _i;
        double _r;
        std::string * _s; // Owned/copied
        Object * _o; // Not owned/copied
    }
    _data;

    // etc...
};
```

And :

```
class HeapValue
{
   //...

   inline void reference() throw()
   {
      ++this->_refCount;
   }

   inline void unreference() throw()
   {
      --this->_refCount )
   }
};

Value & Value::operator = ( const Value & val )
{
    switch( this->_type )
    {
    // ...
    case E_OBJECT :
        switch( val._type )
        {
        // ...
        case E_INTEGER :
            this->_data._o->unreference();
            if( this->_data._o->getRefCount() == 0 ) delete this->_data._o; // Deletion moved here, outside of HeapValue ?
            this->_data._i = val._data.i;
            this->_type = E_INTEGER;
            break;
        // ...
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry i forgot that piece of code.

Comment: `Scope` doesn't have a virtual destructor, which looks dangerous --  how do you delete your objects?

Comment: I will not delete objects using Scope pointers. These objects would be deleted when their reference counter falls to 0. I could also add an empty destructor to Scope, but would it change something ?

Comment: The code has no idea which objects are on the stack and which aren't. If you call unreference() and the _refCount is 0 it will try to delete it. The result is undefined (undefined behavior). This may cause all kinds of errors and generally is not desirable.

Comment: Yes, but i do not plan to create them on the stack.

Comment: Maybe that an object should have a scope instead of being a scope ?

Comment: I think you're getting the idea of "single responsibility" wrong. An object should never *own itself*. Owning something is a responsibility, and so should be done by a dedicated class. You don't want to make copies of your object, but only copies of the owning wrapper, and the owning wrapper should delete the held object when *its* last copy dies.

Comment: @KerrekSB So you're saying that HeapValue should point to an instance of Object that it will create and delete ? Also i read somewhere that it was not wrong to delete this as long as you don't access the object anymore after that, is it ?

Comment: @Virus721: Yes. Like `shared_ptr` does it :-)

Comment: I didn't mention that i was planning to use Object pointers insiode of Value objects. Value objects are variants containing either integers, reals, strings or pointer to Object instances (i.e reference in the script). If HeapValue is an intermediate class between Value and Object (something like value->_heapValue->_object) i will also have to manage the destruction of HeapValue objects since multiple Value objects could reference the same HeapValue.
Maybe that i should move the delete statement outside the HeapValue object and put it in Value. I'll edit my question to describe it.

Answer (score 1):

When `unreference` calls `delete this`, it makes a virtual method call (because the destructor is virtual). If the object is of type `Object`, then the virtual call will point to `Object`'s destructor which will call all of it's parent's destructors, including `Scope`'s.

Just don't delete `Object` instances through `Scope` pointers and don't allocate `HeapValue` instances on stack or copy them.

That said, I would use `std::shared_ptr` for reference counting.

Comment: Okay thanks, i understand better now. Do you think that i should use Scope as a member variable instead of using it as a base class for Object ?

Comment: Hmm, possibly. I haven't given it much thought, but multiple inheritance can sometimes get quite tricky.